# How to align portfolio items in height?

Tags: html, css

I would like to align these items in height:

[image: Portfolio grid]

Since I have little clue of what's going on, I'm going to paste what I THINK it's the relevant code:

```css
#portfolio .portfolio-item {
      margin: 0 0 15px;
      right: 0;
    }
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px;
    }
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption h4 {
      text-transform: none;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption p {
      font-family: "Droid Serif", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Portfolio</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Here I show some of my work.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                <p>click for more</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/img.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>1st job</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                <p>click for more</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>2nd job</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Design</p>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                <p>click for more</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/img3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>3rd job</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal4" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                <p>click for more</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/img4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Beach Tennis Brand</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal5" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                <p>click to watch</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/img5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>NGO "4th job"</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover">
                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                                <p>click for more</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/img6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Design</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">5th job</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Make that a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can reproduce the issue right here. Also, the solution could very well be *flexbox*.

Answer (score 0):

There's maybe a better way of doing this but what i will recommand you to do is to wrap the img element inside a div like this :

```
<div class="img-wrap"><img src="source.png" class="img-full"></div>
```

Then you give the img-wrap 100% width and a fixed height of lets say 200px with an overflow hidden

```
.img-wrap{
width:100%;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
background:#cccccc;
}
```

Last you give the img max-height of 200px;

```
.img-full{
max-width:100%;
max-height:200px;
}
```

it should do the work. This way your image keeps it's proportions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use masonry layout ( search for isotope js in google ) or You can set `min-height:300px;max-height:300px;` ( for example ) for every `.portfolio-item`

For image if You don't want to use masonry, try add one more container for img:

```
.image_container{
   width:100%;
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.image_container img{
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

but Your image will be cropped.